# Is "6 bit packed ASCII" an effective encoding to obscure text data?

Tags: stream-cipher, encoding

I wrote a routine for a former employer that took the low six bits of ASCII text and "compressed" by cramming the bits together, so that 4 bytes reduced to 3. This had the advantage of automatically folding lowercase to uppercase (not reversibly) with no computational effort. (Our text data was supposed to be just upper case letters, digits and punctuation. *Can you say COBOL? I knew you could.*) Note that I also ignored the first 32 ASCII characters as well. (They did not appear in the input data.)

Would this encoding method obfuscate text (where SHOUTING was acceptable) in a way that does not yield readily to simple analysis? The data would be encoded from 4 bytes down to 3 like this - (assume that we are only looking at the low 6 bits of every byte, the high 2 bits are just clipped off):

```
B1 = all 6 bits of first byte + low 2 bits of 2nd byte  
B2 = "upper" 4 bits of 2nd byte + lower 4 bits of 3rd byte  
B3 = last 2 bits of 3rd byte + all 6 bits of 4th byte
```

(Is there a prettier picture to illustrate this?)

Comment: Short answer, no. This is similar to performing Base64 decode on plaintext data. You may have noticed that ASCII letters are actually 7 bits...

Comment: @RichieFrame Yes, but if you can sacrifice lower case, ignoring the two high bits leads to lowercase and uppercase being indistinguishable. Example: Uppercase A is hex 41, lowercase a is hex 61. "It's like, one bit different, you know?" I had an alternative algorithm which only ignored the top bit and compressed 8 bytes to 7... Oh, right, I ignored the whole first 32 ASCII characters as well. Gotta cut corners somehow.

Comment: as @A.Toumantsev says below, there isn't a good way to answer "is this effective" in the absence of real keyed encryption.  What is the threat model?  What resources does the attacker have?  If I'm the attacker, you've already told me everything I need to know to decode the data.

Comment: @bmm6o I am not assuming an "attacker", just someone who should not be able to read something if I do not want them to. Like putting a lock on your diary, or putting it in a locked file drawer. I don't assume that Arnold Schwarzenegger will show up with a crowbar and dynamite.

Comment: If you're comparing it with putting a lock on a diary, then yes this method of obfuscation will keep your little sister from reading your data.

Comment: The world seems to have become a very perverse place with the advent of the Internet: it is no longer local. "My stuff" which used to be safe from 99.9999% of humanity by sheer inconvenience is now available to any person who feels like prying in to it. This is immoral and unstable, and cannot be allowed to continue. Somehow we have to build "locality of access" back in to our systems so that you have to actually "be there" or "be who you really are" to get to something. I cannot imagine how this can be done, but I am sure  that very smart people are working on the problem just now. *Right?*

Comment: And I shouldn't have said that the type of question is unanswerable, it just needs to be more specific, like: How does this transformation affect the byte distribution.

Comment: @bmm6o yes, that is what I was envisioning. Apparently I am not knowledgeable enough to ask the question with the correct terms, but I relied on your knowledge to fill in the gaps. This is pretty common in a computer context. Or, any context of "*interested person asks the experts.*" Tearing the question to pieces is not really useful in that case, but it is surprisingly common on SE, I find.

Comment: "someone who should not be able to read something if I do not want them to" - the main question is if **they** want to. I've typed a fairly long comment below...

Answer (score 2):

No. I actually new how to do such coding on my MSX machine in the mid-eighties (when I was 12). I'm pretty sure I could have decoded it back then. Note that binary code was much more used at that time; you had to code in assembler to get any kind of performance. It was also pretty common to compress things in such a way because you did not have much memory either.

What you're describing is an encoding scheme. Encoding is something different from encryption. Obviously it can obfuscate text, but that obfuscation is just skin deep. This is especially the case if somebody starts to look for strings.

You could however encode to base64 with a different alphabet. That kind of obfuscate things enough that you have to revert the encoding to read it. You could also XOR your scheme with a (multi-)byte pattern to make things less readable for humans.

Comment: I completely agree with all you wrote, except for the initial 'No'. If we re-read the question: is this an obfuscation? Yes. Is it effective? No idea what is meant by effectiveness here. A bit weird that the packing algorithm is lossy but if the input data is guaranteed to always fit within 6 bits - it's OK. Ah, there's a 2nd question in the body about "simple analysis" - to this the answer is, indeed, **No**. Or, more, precisely - it depends on who is going to analyse. :)

Comment: @A.Toumantsev The problem is that 1) it depends on the audience if this is any good as obfuscation; I tried to argue that there are plenty people out there that think in bits and will find this an amusing puzzle *at best* and 2)  that there are plenty schemes that are about as simple as this, but do a much better job at obfuscation.

Comment: yep, agreed. And I'll repeat myself - if someone asks "is this effective" I demand the definition of "effectiveness" in the context of the question. Being what I am and doing what I do, I first read 'effective' as 'fast', in which sense the suggested algo is pretty much 'effective' but that's definitely not what OP means :)

Comment: @A.Toumantsev "effective" in this case means: *Changing readable text in to random-seeming bytes strewn more or less evenly throughout the ASCII code space, where usually detectable patterns of text are not visible and simple methods like Vigenere analysis (on raw bytes) will not work. Also, that it cannot be recovered using techniques available to a non-programmer (short of them obtaining a cryptanalysis tool).* I also like the aspects of a simple fast program that I can write which does not need a key and just rerunning the program reverses it. Effective for my purposes.

Comment: I see. Well, as others pointed out already, "*that obfuscation is just skin deep. This is especially the case if somebody starts to look for strings.*" but if this suits your puposes, no problem...

Comment: @A.Toumantsev Particular question: would a string search reveal anything if the bytes are "shortened" in this way and overlapped together like this? I would think any resemblance to printable ASCII would be entirely gone. I guess I will have to try it, but I don't see how any "readability" would remain in this situation. What am I missing here? Repetition would have to be on a 3 byte interval, which doesn't seem like it would reveal much.

Comment: "I guess I will have to try it, but I don't see how any "readability" would remain in this situation." - indeed the best way is to try it, encode some meaningful text with your method and publish it here.  "What am I missing here?" - you're missing the fact that you are on *Cryptography*.SE and people here think in terms of attacks, security strength, etc. There was a comment above about preventing your "little sister from reading your data", I will add my comment there as well. For someone who **wants** to read you data, you encoding is not an obstacle, for those who don't want ..

Comment: .. to read it, there is no point in any encoding - they are just not interested anyway. And only for a specific case where your data might accidentally appear in front of someone's eyes and you want to discourage them from reading it by making the text look like gibberish - then it might make some sense :)

Comment: @A.Toumantsev ok, why not go for it... "How do I prevent people from reading my data, absolutely, positively, can't fail?" One-Time Pad? Is that the only conceivable option? Because if someone really really wants to, they will, even if they have to move heaven and earth to do it, right? If this is now the world we live in, I have to stick with my method of avoiding car theft: own a car nobody wants because it is brown and 20 years old. Except that no one can steal my car from Romania, anyway. We have created a world that is fundamentally broken, and it needs to be fixed.

Comment: @nocomprende  We'll be banned for chat and offtopic, there are rules here. Your questions, as far as I can see, have been answered.  The rest is offtopic. I wouldn't mind a chat but rules are rules.